# java arraylist example with no symbol resolved

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm just unsure why this isn't working.

```
ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] input = new String[]{"biggest", "next", "not"};
test1.add(input);
```

there's an error in the 3rd line, at add.
My editor just says the symbol cannot be resolved, and just for the test, I typed test1. and ctrl + spaced it to see what it would give me, but no suggestion.
Any help?

Comment: Works okay for me (`ArrayList<String[]> test1 = new ArrayList<>();`)

Answer (score 2):

by using `add` you can just add to the list what you defined in your generic, which would be `String` in your case. This isn´t valid since you try to add an array of `String` to your list. to achive this you could us the `addAll` function like this.

```
ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] input = new String[]{"biggest", "next", "not"};
test1.addAll(Arrays.asList(input));
```

Comment: I'm actually still getting the same "the symbol cannot be resolved"  at addAll....

Comment: in that case could you share your whole class, maybe you are missing an import or you do have an syntax error elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try This: ( Use Arrays.asList()  )

```
String[] input = new String[]{"biggest", "next", "not"};
ArrayList<String> test1 =new ArrayList (Arrays.asList(input));
System.out.println(test1);
```

Or u can use this

```
List<String> test1 =new ArrayList ();
String[] input = new String[]{"biggest", "next", "not"};
Collections.addAll(test1, input);
System.out.println(test1);
```

Output:

```
[biggest, next, not]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arraylist is of type "String" ,  and you are trying to add a "String [ ]" object , you can't do that

if your list is like this

```
ArrayList<String[]> test1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

that's will work you can add the array input as an object